# Run-Time error 3075 Access Syntax Error for combobox Search in Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, debugging

I am learning about how to create a searchbox with combo box. I was learning with a video in youtube :
Access: How to Create Search Form Using Combo box Part 1

However, when I do my code it doesn't work. :/ I get the Run-Time error 3075 Access Syntax Error.

```
Private Sub cboVendorSearch_AfterUpdate()
Dim MyVendor As String
MyVendor = "Select * from Vendors where ([vend_name] = " & Me.cboVendorSearch & ")"
Me.Invoices_subform.Form.RecordSource = MyVendor
Me.Invoices_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Do note: that is not code to search a form but filter a form.

Comment: Thanks! I have been learning SQL and thought it was a code.

Comment: Yes, given code applies filter to form. If you want to do a search and go to record without applying filter that would be different code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming vend_name is a text field, need apostrophe delimiters.

`MyVendor = "SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE [vend_name] = '" & Me.cboVendorSearch & "';"`

Instead of setting RecordSource, an alternative is to set Filter property.

```
Me.Invoices_subform.Form.Filter = "[vend_name] = '" & Me.cboVendorSearch & "'"
Me.Invoices_subform.Form.FilterOn = True
```

Would probably be better to use vendor ID for search criteria. Explore multi-column combobox where the ID field is a hidden column but combobox uses the hidden column for its Value yet displays vend_name to user.

Comment: Private Sub VendorSearch_AfterUpdate()
Dim myVendor As String
myVendor = "SELECT * FROM Vendor WHERE [vend_name] = '" & Me.VendorSearch & "';"
Me.Filter -"[vend_name] = '" & Me.VendorSearch & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub

Comment: the code didn't work :/  I cannot use the ID... i have lots of vendors and cannot remember their numbers when I input them. What else could I do?

Comment: the error is to debug and it shows me in yellow :Private Sub VendorSearch_AfterUpdate()

Comment: It also said compile error: invalid use of property.

Comment: The hyphen after `Me.Filter` should be `=`. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.filter(property)).

Comment: Private Sub VendorSearch_AfterUpdate()
Dim myVendor As String
myVendor = "SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE [vend_name] = '" & Me.VendorSearch & "';"
Me.Filter = "[vend_name] = '" & Me.VendorSearch & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
Now it is not doing anything. vend_name is the column where the vendors are, all unique, it is the Key. and Vendors is my table. :/

Comment: You don't have to remember VendorID. With combobox I describe you select vendor name but the ID is value of combobox. Methods of setting RecordSource or setting Filter property are both common and proven to work. No idea why not working for your situation. Would have to know more about database structure and form design. Oops, corrected my typo for = sign.

Comment: My goof, forgot to adjust code for reference to subform. See revised answer. Did you test RecordSource code with text delimiters? That should have worked.

Comment: Hi! thanks where is the revised answer? I'll try it again.

Comment: Thanks it seems that I am getting closer to make it work. Now I have a message saying vend_name Enter Parameter Va...  I used to fix those types of issues. How can I fix this one? it seems it cannot find the path right?

Comment: I fixed it!!!! I had to write VendorName which was what was written on my combobox. Thank you!!!!